# SailsJS expose data to client

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I try to find the equivalent to [express-expose](https://github.com/expressjs/express-expose) for sailsJS. I want to expose some data to the client. How can do this ? I did find anything in sails documentation for this.

I try *sails.exposeGlobals* but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a controller and add you configs or custom data to the response. it is easy.

Check we.js core plugin for example of how to do this in: https://github.com/wejs/we-plugin-core/blob/master/api/controllers/MainController.js#L34

Comment: It would be great to have just to put sails.expose(mydatatoexpose) like express-expose :) but it's ok this way ^^thanks !